# In-memory testing using Jersey Test Framework, TestNG and Maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey, testng, jersey-test-framework

I am building a web project which uses Maven for building and uses Jersey for RESTful API. I have written unit tests using TestNG and Jersey Test Framework and am running them in-memory and not on a web server.

In my tests I make a JDBC call to my MySQL database and get some results. The tests run fine when I run from within Eclipse using the TestNG for Eclipse plugin. However, when I try running from Maven using either of the two commands:

```
    mvn clean package
```

or

```
    mvn test
```

I get the output as shown below:

[image]

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.teamlink.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>teamlink-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
    <name>teamlink-services</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>teamlink-services-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.44</version>
                <scope>runtime, test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
                <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.10</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Your help is appreciated as this is driving me crazy. I am not sure what am I missing exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your `pom.xml` file.

First the scope for `mysql-connector-java` in `dependencyManagement` section is defined incorrectly:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.44</version>
            <scope>runtime, test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Maven doesn't allow defining comma separated list of scopes. In your case it is enough to specify `runtime` scope as then library will be available during test execution and runtime. So it should be

```
            <scope>runtime</scope>
```

Next `dependencyManagement` section is used only to declare "standard" usage of the dependency in project and it's child projects. To actually include the library in you project it should be listed in project `dependencies`. And your pom lacks

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

among project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Aleh. I will try that out and let you know how it goes. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm! Thank you Aleh for your help.